# How can I get the size that a drake target takes on disk?

Tags: r, drake-r-package

When need to understand my drake plan, `vis_drake_graph()` comes in handy, and it displays the time that each target took to run. This is very helpful in figuring out whether targets should be broken down to reduce re-run time on small changes.

My need is related: Because many of my long-running targets involve the manipulation of large data sets, it is important for me to understand the **size that each cached target takes on disk**. This would help me understand if targets should be combined to prevent the storage of huge intermediate results (even if it would increase re-run time in case of a change to the combined target).

Examining both the config object and the intermediate object returned by `drake_graph_info()`, I have not been able to find this information. I was thinking that it might be very useful to have this information, and potentially other information (such as the time a target was last run) shown by specifying parameters to `vis_drake_graph()` or even just by examining the config object manually.

So the question is, is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) uses a package called [`storr`](https://github.com/richfitz/storr) to handle the storage of targets. As far as I know, [`storr`](https://github.com/richfitz/storr) does not have an easy way to get file size information. However, at least for the default `storr_rds()` cache type, maybe it should. You could [request it as a feature](https://github.com/richfitz/storr/issues/new). If implemented, we would have an easier version of the following workaround, at least in the case of RDS caches.

```r
library(drake)
load_mtcars_example()
make(my_plan, verbose = 0L)
cache <- get_cache() # or storr::storr_rds(".drake")
root <- cache$driver$path
hash <- cache$driver$get_hash("small", namespace = "objects")
path <- file.path(root, "data", paste0(hash, ".rds"))
file.exists(path)
#> [1] TRUE
file.size(path)
#> [1] 404
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

[`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) is all about repetition and runtime, and [`storr`](https://github.com/richfitz/storr) is all about data and storage. As we think about new features, I would prefer to keep these separate goals in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer @landau, using this info I implemented a function that reports the size of a target, allowing one to quickly check the sizes of all targets in a plan:

```
library(tibble)
library(drake)

get_target_size <- function(target) {
    cache <- get_cache() # or storr::storr_rds(".drake")
    root  <- cache$driver$path
    hash  <- cache$driver$get_hash(target, namespace = "objects")
    path  <- file.path(root, "data", paste0(hash, ".rds"))
    if ( file.exists(path) ) {
        file.size(path)
    } else {
      NA
    }
}

load_mtcars_example()
make(my_plan, verbose = 0L)
tibble( target = my_plan$target, 
        size = sapply(my_plan$target, get_target_size))
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   target                  size
   <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 report                    55
 2 small                    404
 3 large                    463
 4 regression1_small       2241
 ...
```

I think that will suffice for my needs, and understand that it might not make sense to implement it as part of drake unless there was a more general solution that worked for any storage type.